# The model TokenProxy is already registered in app 'authtoken'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am facing this problem with migrating in Django admin after I updated the app name 'rest_framework.authtoken' in django project settings.

It gives me error The model TokenProxy is already registered in app 'authtoken'.

I know I should have added this and migrate before creating super user but now I have already created the project and migrated lots of models and there is a data in it. Can help me how I can resolve this problem.

I also tried to undo migrations with command python manage.py migrate books but it again does not recognize the word books.

Please help me with this.

Here is my apps in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'traderskamp_app',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

Here is the exact error:

File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\authtoken\admin.py", line 51, in 
admin.site.register(TokenProxy, TokenAdmin)
File "C:\Users\Anwar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 126, in register
raise AlreadyRegistered(msg)
django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model TokenProxy is already registered in app 'authtoken'.

Answer (score 1):

might be a bit late but I would search your project for this.

`admin.site.register(TokenProxy)`

you are likely registering TokenProxy somewhere in your code and that is causing a conflict with authtoken